# Spring Data Persist entity in Log Table before each save()

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

im working in a spring boot project and i have a requirement to save the old object in a specific table before each new save ; this my man entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="demande")
public class Demande {

  @Id
  private Long id;

 // all properties

}


@Entity
@Table(name="demande_log")
public class DemandeLog {

  @Id
  private Long id;

 // all properties

}
```

what im trying to do is before each `demandeRepository.save(demande);`
i want to save the old demande object (current row in database) as `DemandeLog` in my demande_log table.

do you have any idea how  using spring data, i know that there is a listener @PrePersist in JPA.. but i want to do it properly.

Regards.

Comment: 1. JPA callbacks (Pre/Post listeners) must not interact with db/persistent context. 2. `CrudRepository#save` is not the only option to update entity in DB - any query may cause HBN to flush changes into DB. The options are: 1. DB triggers. 2. [HBN Listeners](https://medium.com/@rachit.dixit/the-magic-of-hibernate-listeners-with-spring-boot-47b61ef60bd4). 3. [Envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Envers](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-envers). It is easy to set up and gives you a complete change log.

Comment: thanks for the link but it's empty there no example on how to implement it

Comment: The documentation is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/envers/docs/current/reference/html/